# How to keep the highest value of each date for each 50 states in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

Since the dataset is cumulative for each month, I want to keep only the last row of each month for each of the 50 states. The [Sample Dataset Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL8Dx.png)  here is what the top looks like sorted by name. What functions do I need from tidyverse or dplyr to get it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot copy/paste data from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use this `dummy` data looks similar to your data,

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  name = c("Alabama","Alabama","Alabama","Alabama","Alabama","Alabama"),
  bla = c(1:6),
  as_of_date = c("3/26/2020","3/31/2020","4/6/2020","4/13/2020","4/21/2020","4/28/2020"),
  month = c(3,3,4,4,4,4)
)

     name bla as_of_date month
1 Alabama   1  3/26/2020     3
2 Alabama   2  3/31/2020     3
3 Alabama   3   4/6/2020     4
4 Alabama   4  4/13/2020     4
5 Alabama   5  4/21/2020     4
6 Alabama   6  4/28/2020     4
```

You may try,

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>%
  mutate(as_of_date = as.Date(as_of_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  arrange(name, as_of_date) %>% # to order by date, state, in case that your data is not ordered as an image
  group_by(name, month) %>%
  filter(row_number() == n())

  name      bla as_of_date month
  <chr>   <int> <date>     <dbl>
1 Alabama     2 2020-03-31     3
2 Alabama     6 2020-04-28     4
```